# How do I undo "ip link set name"?

Tags: linux, networking

I have renamed a network interfaces under Redhat 7 (or CentOS 7) using `ip link set ens3f0 name xxx`. How do I undo this? I would like to get the predictable interface name back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing more to it than:

```
ip link set xxx name ens3f0
```

You can run `udevadm info /sys/class/net/xxx` to see what name was originally assigned by udev's "predictable naming" rules (under ID_NET_NAME).

Normally `ip link` changes are not permanent and the original name will return after a reboot.